# Target.Value gives error when refreshing database

Tags: excel, vba

My sub routine

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 MsgBox Target.value
End Sub
```

Throws type mismatch error when I refresh connection to database. I have actually connected excel to database. 
What is the value of Target.value when I refresh database connection?

Comment: You can find out what Target is by changing your MsgBox to display Target.Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type Mismatches are *usually* (I stress usually) easy to debug.  Without knowing exactly what Target is, it's difficult to say why the error happens.

My first guess is that the range spans more than one cell.  For example, this code also gives a "Type Mismatch" error:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:a2")
    MsgBox r.Value
End Sub
```

If the range is a single cell, then maybe it's in error or some other "Range Type".
I found [the following code](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip62.htm) which will help you determine a cell's type.